# Selenium and Python with Search bar that does not allow Enter

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to webscrape [this website](https://www.msci.com/our-solutions/esg-investing/esg-ratings/esg-ratings-corporate-search-tool/issuer/verizon-communications-inc/IID000000002188695) and search by company, but it's search feature is wonky.

I am currently trying to wait until the element is visible but I can't quite crack it. I am new to this, so ***answers with full code*** greatly appreciated!

In this example, we start out on Verison, I want to go to Tesla.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('Path/to/Chromedriver')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    
company_to_search = 'TESLA, INC.'

url = 'https://www.msci.com/our-solutions/esg-investing/esg-ratings/esg-ratings-corporate-search-tool/issuer/verizon-communications-inc/IID000000002188695'

driver.get(url)
search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "_esgratingsprofile_keywords")))
search.send_keys(company_to_search)
search.submit()
```

Comment: Presumably search is a textbox and if send_keys works to fill in the textbox then you need to find the enclosing form element then call submit on that, not on the textbox.

Comment: actually I think Selenium's "submit()" can be used on any form element to submit the form.  I'm confused about the question, did you get an exception when you use your code?  What is happening not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for option and click on it:

```
driver.get(url)
search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "_esgratingsprofile_keywords")))
search.send_keys(company_to_search)
option = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[.='%s']" % company_to_search)))
option.click()
```